# How to split date and find out if day is Sunday in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has a 'date' input field:

```
<form method='post' id="register-form" novalidate>
  Date: <input type="date" name="date" id="date"/>
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Now what I want, when I select a date that equals to "Sunday" it should then prompt me that "You've selected Sunday". How is it possible to make it in jquery.validator method?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript's `Date.getDay()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var d = new Date();

    alert(d.getDay());
  } );
```

As stated you don't need jQuery to use this but I've wrapped it in jQuery for your pleasure. As stated by nc3b the result its 0 based where 0 is Sunday.

Comment: You've used the built-in function to get the current day of the system which I don't need. What I need is to split the date when I select from date list in my form and check if the date I've select equals to "Sunday" then it must prompt me a message.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on this

```
    $("body").on('change','#date',function(){
   var date = new Date($("#date").val());
   if(date.getDay()=='0')
    alert("You selected sunday");
    });
```

Comment: i am not sure why its not working. getDay() returns value from 0-6 as 0 is sunday , 1 is monday, 2 is tuesday and so.